# Is my process to get the answer the correct way to solve the following trigonometry problems?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Q1) The number of integral values of ' a ' for which the equation :  cos 2x + a sin x = 2a - 7 possesses a solution is ?

**My Solution**

cos 2x + a sin x = 2a - 7

=> 2 sin^2 x - a sin x - 8 + 2a = 0

Since sine oscillates between -1 and 1 ,

so in the equation ' a ' will range from

a = 2 to a = 6

=> 5 values of a . The answer is correct . I am not sure if the process is correct . I mean how can one surely say the the ' expression ' will give extreme values at -1 & 1 .

---

Q2) The number of possible triplets ( a , b , c ) such that

a + b cos 2x + c sin^2 x = 0 .

**My solution :**

Convert cos2x in terms of sin , then I got a = -b

So intuitively : Infinity which is the correct answer .

Is it the correct approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: your approaches seem fine, and pretty good for the most part. Were you supposed to find how many *integer* triples have these properties? If so, it's important to say that in the question. I'm going to assume that.

For the first, you might try the substitution $u = \sin x$. You then get
$$
2u^2 -au -8 + 2a = 0
$$
which is a quadratic in $u$. You can solve that, and determine which values of $u$ are real (as a function of $a$) and which lie between $-1$ and $1$. For each of these, there's at least one solution $x$, because the sine function is surjective onto the interval $[-1, 1]$.

For the second, I'd use $\cos 2x = 1 - 2\sin^2 x$ to simplify, and get

$$
a + b + (c-2b) (\sin^2 x) = 0.
$$
Now if you just look at $\sin x = 0$ (which has the solution $x = 0$), you simply need that $a + b = 0$, so there are, as you observe, infinitely many solutions. You can even enumerate an infinite set: $(a, b, c) = (n, -n, -2n)$ for $n \in \mathbb N$, which makes it pretty compelling.

Answer (score 1):

In Q1 you have solved the equation for a as follows (with t=sin x):

a=(2t^2-8)/(t-2)

and you should theoretically examine whether the full range of that expression on the interval -1<=t<=1 is defined by its values at the end points t=-1 and t=1.

In general that examination would require finding extreme values by taking the derivative with respect to t. In this particular case, however, the expression simplifies to the linear expression

a=2t+4

A linear expression has no extreme values (its derivative is constant) so in this case you can safely determine the range by looking at the end points only.

In Q2 it is not a priori clear whether x has a fixed given value, or whether we are looking for triplets (a,b,c) such that the equation has at least one real solution for x. Assume the first interpretation. Nor do you state explicitly that a,b and c have to be integers.

If sin x is nonzero then a and b can have arbitrary values and c is given by solving the equation. If sin x is zero then b has to be -a and c is arbitrary. In both cases the answer remains infinite, with two degrees of freedom.

Even under the additional restriction that a, b and c must be integers the answer remains infinite because one can choose b to be an arbitrary integer, a=-b and c=2b.

Comment: Thanks . I knew my approach isnt wrong , but I didn't know why it gives the answer correctly in this case . So I can take the extreme values of the variable if the differentiation of the expression is linear .

Comment: You can safely take the endpoints of the interval if the expression itself (not its derivative) is linear.